# How to use Electron menu to execute angular 7 navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, electron, angular7

I am using angular 5.2.11 with election version 3.0.7 and am trying to use the Electron menu to navigate to an angular 5 component. When I click on the electron menu it navigates to the page but my component only executes the constructor not any of the angular lifecycle hooks until I click in the electron window. Then the page loads and works as it's supposed to.

menu.js file:

```
const { Menu } = require('electron');
const menuTemplate = [
      label: 'Maintenance',
      submenu: [
          {
              label: 'Sar Maintenance',
          }
      ];

menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate);    
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);

exports.ApplicationMenu = menu;
```

index.ts file:

```
const { app } = require('electron');
const BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow

let ipcm = require('electron').ipcMain;
let appmenu = require('./menu.js');
let menu = appmenu.ApplicationMenu;
let mainWindow;

function createMainWindow () {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width:  800, height: 800});
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

    menu.items[1].click = () => {    // Sar Mainenance
        mainWindow.webContents.send('goto-sar', 'sarArg');
    }

    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null
    });
}

app.on('ready', createMainWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createMainWindow()
  }
})

ipcm.on('page-nav-complete', () => {
    console.log('NavComplete');
    app.focus();
});
```

Angular app.component.ts:

```
let ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
app.component.ts constructor:

ipcRenderer.on('goto-sar', function(sender, arg) {
  this.openSar();
});
```

angular method in app.component.ts:

```
openSar () {
    this._router.navigate(['/sargen']);
    ipcRenderer.send('page-nav-complete');
}
```

It seems mainWindow is not getting focus?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The title suggests that it's a solutoin for Angular 7, but your question is speaking about Angular 5. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use `NgZone.run()`. More here - [Angular NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone). That's what I had to do to make Angular work with Electron and using route navigation inside `ipcRenderer`.

#### Example

```
import { OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
let ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        ipcRenderer.on('goto-sar', (event, arg) => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                this.openSar();
            });
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Worked like a charm.  I've been searching for months for an answer.

Comment: For me your solution is not working, I get the following error: **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in ...** . I work with Angular 7.

Comment: @laurentIsRunning It's not related to my answer or this question, you are trying to use `fs` which could be FileSystem and you don't have that module installed. If you need further help, ask specific question.

Comment: @Oen44 Thanks for your feedback. I have this package installed and it is referenced by the electron module. I think that since Angular 6 ng build does not allow to reference fs... so it seems to me related to the question or your answer.

Comment: @laurentIsRunning This question is not about error you are getting. Update to Angular 7 if you have problems with compatibility. I have worked with electron and Angular 7 without any problem.

Comment: @Oen44 thanks for your answer. I'm actually running with the last version of angular and get this problem when i try to use the ipcrenderer. I will open a new question on stackoverflow then.

Comment: I've followed the follwing guide and it worked for me : https://dev.to/michaeljota/integrating-an-angular-cli-application-with-electron---the-ipc-4m18